Error retrieving API data (Symfony - react)
I'm developing a service exchange site in Symfony and React.
I have a service creation feature, where I need to retrieve the id of the current user and then POST the service creation form. I'm able to retrieve and send the user id on the back end, but I can't retrieve the API content on the front end.
The id is retrieved using an API I created for symfony:
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;

class ProfilController extends AbstractController
{
    private TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage;
    public function __construct( TokenStorageInterface $storage )
        {
            $this->tokenStorage = $storage;
        }
        
    #[Route('/profil', name: 'app_profil')]
    public function index()
    {
        $user=$this->tokenStorage->getToken();

        return new JsonResponse(
            [
                'user_id'=>$user->getUser()->getId()
            ], Response::HTTP_OK, ['Content-Type' => 'application/json']);
            
            
    }
}

However, when I try to retrieve my id on the REACT side, I get a 500 error and the message: Error while retrieving data:
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";


function User(){

   const [userId, setUserId] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

 
  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/profil`,
      {
        method: 'GET',
        }
    );
      
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Erreur lors de la récupération des données');
      }

      const jsonData = await response.json();
      
      console.log(jsonData);
      setUserId(jsonData['user_id']);
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {fetchData();
}, []);

if (loading) return <div>Chargement en cours...</div>;

if (error) return <div>Erreur: {error.message}</div>;

  return (
    <div>
        
        Welcome, User {userId}!
        </div>
  )
}

export default User;

I don't understand where the error is, when I test the API (http://127.0.0.1:8000/profil) on the browser I get a valid response:
{"user_id":31}

I don't know wich authentication method you use. You should pass the session cookie to your fetch method or the jwt token if you're are working with jwt.
